# Changing collection from CollectionChanged event

Tags: silverlight, events, exception, observablecollection

I want to update collection after it was changed but I can't seem to get "away" from this exception:

*Cannot change ObservableCollection during a CollectionChanged or PropertyChanged event.*

Inside event handler I unsubscribe from Collection changed event before changing anything to prevent infinite loops and after changes are made i subscribe again to same event.

```
private void CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    data.CollectionChanged -= CollectionChanged;
    data.Add("Item");
    data.CollectionChanged += CollectionChanged;
}
```

I tried using Dispatcher to call data.Add("Item"), but no luck :(

Comment: The best solution here would be to rework the way you are doing things - it would be unusual to add an item to a collection in the middle of its CollectionChanged event handler, regardless of hooking/unhooking of the handler. Basically, this code smells in several different ways.

Comment: To give more insight of what I try to accomplish is service pager. pager is hooked to collection and when page is changed, collection changes. At that point i request backend for data with page index and when it is returned - colletion is cleared and filled with new data. I use this RadQueryableCollectionView from Telerik that allows you to say that there are more items in collection and total item count without real items being there. It all works fine if service call is made (async) since event handler is finished. But when using mocks - data returns instantly and u remain inside event...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are unsubscribing from the event within the event which has yet to complete.  Drop back and re-evaluate why you are adding to the collection and determine if there is another way to accomplish what you need.